# How to post json parameter in [FromBody](raw) in .core (POSTMAN)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've a method `[Post]` in .core 3 project. as well as:
And i will use post with 10 json parameter:

```
[
  {
    "os": "android",
    "type": "www",
    "versionCode": 123,
    "operand": "fofdr",
    "forceUpdate": false,
    "title": "dsfs",
    "message": "fdsf",
    "action": "act",
    "positiveButton": "btn1",
    "negativeButton": "test",
    "messageType": "sadad"
  }
]
```

and:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateStartMessage")]
        public IActionResult CreateStartMessage([FromBody] string os, string type, int versionCode, string operand, bool forceUpdate, string title,
            string message, string action, string positiveButton, string negativeButton,string messageType)
        {
            try
            {

             ...
                return Ok(resultApi);
            }



        }
```

How i pass json parameters with POSTMAN to this method api?

Comment: How to send json with Postman is described in the docs: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/ - but your json will not work with your message signature. You don't have 10 parameters but ONE parameter which is a list of objects and the object has properties os, type, ... You'll need to create a class that models your json structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with the hints from @Christoph Lütjen:

```
class MyMessage {
  public string Os { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public int VersionCode { get; set; }
  public string Operand { get; set; }
  public bool ForceUpdate { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
  public string Action { get; set; }
  public string PositiveButton { get; set; }
  public string NegativeButton { get; set; }
  public string MessageType { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("CreateStartMessage")]
public IActionResult CreateStartMessage([FromBody]MyMessage clientMessage) {
    return Ok(resultApi);
}
```

Comment: clientMessage who i define?

Comment: danke mein Freund!